# MAUI exe файл мгновенно закрывается

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

Сделал рабочее и практическое пустое MAUI приложение с дефолтными контролами, но, что интересно, если я выполняю запуск из студии, то окошко есть, все работает, а вот запуск .exe файла из проводника не приводит ни к чему, будто, оно мгновенно закрывается. Ошибок и предупреждений никаких нет.

Comment: Журнал ошибок Windows смотрите.